# Read data file JSON to JAVA

Tags: java, json

I have a problem with JSON; I can not read file from `portblock` but `webblock` can be done

This is `test.json`

```
{
    "webblock" : ["www.google.com", "www.youtube.com", "www.facebook.com"],
    "portblock" : [{
            "key" : "80",
            "value" : "tcp"
        }, {
            "key" : "70",
            "value" : "udp"
        }
    ]
}
```

and this is code I used display `webblock`.

```
JSONArray msg = (JSONArray) jsonObject.get("webblock");
Iterator<String> iterator = msg.iterator();
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    System.out.println(iterator.next());
    block_web(iterator.next());
}
```

Help me to display key and value of `portblock`.

Comment: So what exactly is the problem?

Comment: You are calling `next()` twice in your loop, which means you are getting separate values for each call. Store result of `next()` in String variable and use it instead of `iterator.next()`.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look a Jackson. This code should work:

1. Create the Pojo

   ```
   public class DomainName {

        List<String> webblock;
        List<PortBlock> portblock;
        //getter and setters
   }

   public class PortBlock{
        Integer port;
        String value;
        //getter and setters
   }
   ```
2. Map to the Domain Class

   ```
   ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
   objectMapper.readValue(YOUR_JSON_STRING, DomainName.class)
   ```